# Need Help Converting Boolean

Tags: php, boolean

this is actually WordPress but I think it is more of PHP question.

I am using SMOF framework (it is for theme option setting) and flexslider. TO combine bothe of them, in one of flexslider option, I have to use whether "true" or "false". The thing is, SMOF returns "0" and "1" instead of "true" or "false" - the word. So I need to convert "0" to "false" and "1" to "true"

I have this code:

```
function isBoolean($slider_loop) {
    $slider_loop = $smof_data['slider_loop'];
   if ($slider_loop === "true") {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
   return $slider_loop;
}
```

..., and then in flexslider's "side":

```
animationLoop: "<?php echo isBoolean($slider_loop); ?>"
```

but it is not working.

Ideally, it should be something like this:

```
animationLoop: "<?php echo $smof_data['slider_loop'] 
// this return "0" and "1", while it should be "true" or "false" for flexslider to work ?>"
```

So, how should I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `json_encode` is good for altering PHP structures in javascript constructs.

Comment: Thanks Wrikken, I may need to use it later.

Comment: Why later? Why not `echo json_encode($whateveryourreturnis);`, and it will dutifully make that `true` or `false` if that's what that variable is....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about you take advantage of dynamic typing and type casting ? It's as simple as:

```
return (bool)$smof_data['slider_loop'];
```

..

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried using type casting but I think I applied it wrong. Turned out it is very simple.

I commented the function above and simply use this directly in flexslider's side and it works.

`animationLoop: "<?php echo (bool)$smof_data['slider_loop']; ?>"`

Thanks again :)

Comment: Note: this will not output `'true'` or `'false'` as you wanted, but `1` or nothing at all. See http://codepad.org/gbkzXsnE

Comment: If it's the actual string and not the the boolean value just wrap it in a var_export.. ( 'false' === ( $boolean_represented_as_string = var_export( (bool)0, true ) ) &&  ( 'true' === ( $boolean_represented_as_string = var_export( (bool)1, true ) ) ... that said, I do believe OP is just having a case of an XY Problem ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem )

Answer (score 2):

replace

```
animationLoop: "<?php echo isBoolean($slider_loop); ?>"
```

with

```
animationLoop: "<?php echo ($slider_loop == 1) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>"
```

If you echo `true` instead of `"true"`, it will outputs `1` and nothing incase of `false`.

Comment: Thanks Nauphal, very fast reply! (under 1 minute if I see the time correctly lol) Unfortunately it doesn't work, but again, thank you, I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question completely. 
You say SMOF returns "0" and "1" but you make a check like this:

```
if($slider_loop === "true")
```

well, first **"true"** is not the same as **true**. One is string, the other boolean.

I think I would do it like this:

```
   $slider_loop = (int)$smof_data['slider_loop'];
   if ($slider_loop) {
      return true;
   } else {
      return false;
   }
```

Comment: also note that echo'ing true and false is not gonna give result ;)

Comment: Also, function name `isBoolean` is very misleading there.

Comment: Thanks guys, I am still learning and yes, I have / had doubt regarding triple "=" and double. Experimenting (read: changing the code a lot :P). It is not working but thanks for the lessons :)

Answer (score 0):

`1` and `'1'` are already truthy, and `0` and `'0'` are already falsy, so you can use them directly in your if statements. [Read more about PHP Booleans](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

If you need to echo out a string based on the bool, i.e., `'true'` or `'false'`, you can simplify with the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php):

```
echo $value ? 'true' : 'false';
```

In your case:

```
echo $smof_data['slider_loop'] ? 'true' : 'false';
```

Comment: It doesn't work Jamie..

animation: "<?php echo $smof_data['slider_animation']; ?>", //work, but not boolean
animationLoop: "<?php echo $smof_data['slider_loop'] ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>" // doesn't work
// animationLoop: "<?php echo (bool)$smof_data['slider_loop']; ?>" work, I commented it to try

I had been googling / looking for answers (found 2 on this site - pretty much the same  answers as yours), and from my limited knowledge and experience I also think that it should work, but somehow it doesn't.

Comment: If you are indeed receiving either `1`, `'1'`, `0`, or `'0'`, and looking to output either `'true'` or `'false'`, I can't see how it wouldn't work. [This demo](http://codepad.org/HIE9v6sR) tests such values. As such, I think we're looking at, as smassey said, an XY Problem.